# What is an easy way to write a stored procedure in Oracle using SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Here is the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE show @faculty VARCHAR(20) 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM tutor
    WHERE title LIKE @faculty+'%'
END
```

Here is the procedure execution:

```
EXEC show 'FI'
```

How can I rewrite this for SQL Developer?

Comment: Drop the @, just say `faculty`, and use Oracle syntax for concatenation: `where title like faculty || '%'`.

Comment: I assume you are coming from a SQL Server background.  In Oracle, a procedure cannot just do a `SELECT` like this.  If you want a procedure to return something to the caller, it would need an `OUT` parameter.  You generally don't use procedures for things that do not modify database state in Oracle.  You could instead write a function that returns a `sys_refcursor`.  If your actual code has meaningful amount of logic in it, I'd guess that you'd be better off with a view instead.

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

With Oracle **12** you can do this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE show(p_faculty varchar)
AS
  cur SYS_REFCURSOR; 
BEGIN 
  OPEN cur FOR 
    SELECT * 
    FROM tutor
    WHERE title LIKE p_faculty || '%';
  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(cur); 
END; 
/
```

Then run it with:

```
exec show_x ('FI');
```